# Local JSON file editing with HTML/JS

Tags: python

I have a python app that uses two dictionaries.
They are used to display an image or gif based on a string input.
The string comes from an RFID scanner reading tags.

I want to make it easy for anyone to edit which file is associated with each ID.
This will be run locally in a linux environment (Raspberry Pi).
I have an HTML page with a table on it like this:

| ID | anatomical location | File |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1313213212 | Left apex | c:/users/etc |
| 1313541324 | Right apex | c:/users/etc |
| 3423541324 | Sub xiphoid | c:/users/etc |

The 'file' box would be the only one that would be a form element to allow the user to choose which image is associated with that ID.

When clicking 'submit' how do I save the ID and File information in a JSON file like this:

```
"1313213212": "c:/users/etc/picture1.png"
```

so it could be loaded in the Python script as a dictionary?

Comment: HTML and Javascript cannot write to local files.  You could use something like `pysimplegui`, or you could just do a simple web app.  Both are practical solutions.

Comment: @TimRoberts not true anymore apparently: https://developer.chrome.com/articles/file-system-access/ the demo works in latest version of chrome: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/text-editor/

Comment: Looks like chrome, edge, safari, and opera are slowly supporting local file access: https://caniuse.com/native-filesystem-api